# Using VB GET Request for Google Custom Search API; URL not found or Illegal Request

Tags: vb.net

I'm creating a program in VB and trying to issue a GET request to Google's Custom Search API.

Based on the code I've tried, I've gotten two responses:

> The requested URL /customsearch/v1 was not found on this server

or

> Your client has issued a malformed or illegal request

I've tried playing around with the variables but I can't seem to figure out why I'm getting these errors. Here's my code:

```
Dim strHTTP As String

strHTTP = "GET /customsearch/v1"
strHTTP = strHTTP & "q=raptors"
strHTTP = strHTTP & "&key=" & mykey
strHTTP = strHTTP & "&cx=" & cxvar
strHTTP = strHTTP & " HTTP/1.1" & vbCrLf
strHTTP = strHTTP & "Host: googleapis.com" & vbCrLf
strHTTP = strHTTP & "Accept: application/json" & vbCrLf
strHTTP = strHTTP & vbCrLf

Web.SendData strHTTP
```

The response I get from this is:

> The requested URL /customsearch/v1 was not found on this server

When I should be getting search results.

Comment: What is the `Web` variable?